# How do the libraries handle the tick symbol syntax behind the scene in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some libraries uses the given below syntax in Javascript. Is the syntax valid in Javascript? If not, how do the libraries handle it behind the scene.

```
const button = css`
position: fixed;
bottom: 10%;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
z-index: 200;
`;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is valid syntax in JS.

Example:

```
function fun(){
   console.log('triggered..!');
}
fun``
```

prints "triggered..!" on console.

this is called "Tagged templates"

more information check here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

when you add closed backticks at end of js variable it will treat it as function call, function will be called with arguments which you pass between backticks.